# ObjectInputStream and read double in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Variables */
        int size = 10;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = "result.dat";
        ObjectInputStream inputStream;
        double[] d = new double[size];
        int j=0;

        /* Codes */
        try{
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

            while(true) d[j++] = inputStream.readDouble();

            inputStream.close();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(fileName+" found error");
            System.exit(0);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(fileName+" reading error");
        }

    }
}
```

This program read 10 double numbers from file(result.dat).
I think this codes are no problem.
But unfortunately, this codes are not work.
If I change the `while(true) d[j++] = inputStream.readDouble();` to
 `for(i=0; i<size; i++) d[i] = inputStream.readDouble();`, codes are work well.
Of course I use `for` sentence and solve this problem. But I wonder.
Why is that?

Comment: your problem is solved. so what answer do you want ?

Comment: Why while sentence and inputStream.close() can't use in same code is my problem.

Comment: The `while (true)` version will throw `EOFException` when you reach the end of the stream. That's the only difference in the behaviour of the two versions. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Object Stream is intended for writing Objects.  Either you should `writeObject(doubleArray)` or use DataOutputStream to write doubles.

Comment: 'Are not work' is not a problem description, or valid English either. The close should be in a `finally` block. Your catch blocks should print the actual exception, not some message of your own devising. This is not 'no problem' code.

Answer (score 1):

`inputStream.close();` is unreachable.

the while loop will continue until there's nothing to read, then it will throw and error and be caught, at which point your IDE realises it will never run `inputStream.close();` .

The for loop will work because it can end without an exception being thrown, and it is possible for `inputStream.close();` to actualy be run.

Comment: I did that. Make `catch(EOFException e)` but result was same.

Comment: @jake You'll have to show the code for that. Obviously you should close the input when you catch `EOFException`.

Comment: @ jake you need to use the for loop, or a variable instead of `true`, otherwise you're still going to have unreachable code.

Answer (score -1):

Your  problem with the `while` loop is that you never "quit" the loop, even when there is nothing more to read, so you never reach the next statement (`inputStream.close();`).

The solution would be to add a check for `j` value in the loop and a `break;`statement if the test is true, or to replace `while(true)` with `while(j < 10)`.

Semantically, `for` should be used when you know the number of iteration, and `while` should be used when you don't know the number of iteration. Here you know the number of iteration, so the `for` loop is the best solution.

Comment: `d` is an array reference, and doesn't change within the loop, but in any case it won't magically assume a special value at end of stream.

Answer (score -1):

When you are using `for` loop, you are iterating `size` times.

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
```

When you are using `while` loop, you are passing `true` making it an infinite loop.

```
while(true)
```

So, to make it work, change loop to-

```
i = 0;
while(i < size){
// YOUR CODE GOES HERE
i++;
}
```

Comment: this does the exact same thing as a for loop but less compact and probably slower?

Comment: And it isn't an infinite loop. It terminates at end of stream with an `EOFException`.

Comment: @Thedudxo I haven't checked if it will be slower. Any hints why?

Comment: @EJP Could you share the result.dat file, expected output and actual output?